# Angular6 material: mat autocomplete displayWith doesnt display selected object

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I have a mat-autocomplete list box. The issue is when I select any option from the list box, it doesnt display anything on the input box.

```
  <form [formGroup]="SForm" id="Form" style="width:100%;height:70%" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Direction" aria-label="Assignee"  formControlName="direction" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
     <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" placeholder="Direction" 
     [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let directions of filteredDirectionList | async" 
    [value]="directions.value">{{directions.name}}</mat-option>                                            
    </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>                       
    </form>
```

Below is the .ts file

```
// .ts file

   export const directionList: Array<any> = [{ name: 'Inbound', value: 'I' 
  }, { name: 'Outbound', value: 'O' }];

 ngOnInit() {
  this.SForm= this.formBuilder.group({
  direction: [null],
   });
       this.filterLists();
  }

 displayFn(direction?: any) : string | undefined {
return direction ? direction.name : undefined;;
}

 filterLists() {
this.filteredDirectionList = 
 this.SForm.controls.direction.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith<string | any>(''),
  map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
  map(name => name ? this._filter(name, directionList) : 
 this.directionList.slice())
  );
 }

 private _filter(name: string, lists: any[]): any[] {
const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

return lists.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) 
 === 0);
 }
```

Below is the auto complete list box on display

[image: Listsbox]

But on selection I dont get the display name.

[image: No display name]

There are no console log errors too. 
Something I am missing.

Env:angular6, TS 2.7.2, material 6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `displayWith` function's argument is the object or variable that is set using the option's `value` input. In your case, you are setting `'directions.value` as the option value, but expecting the directions object itself. Change that. The simple solution is to use `[value]="directions"` but then you will probably need to change how your form works since the form control value will now be the same object instead of the value member.